# How to paste formula value as text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am using below VBA to paste data as values for a single cell B3.

```
Sub pastevalues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("data")
    ws.Range("B3").Copy
    ws.Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I would like to do the same for range of columns. How can I do that instead of writing same formula for each cell. I would like to use this formula starting from B3,C3,D3,E3,F3 till their corresponding last cell.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, try changing `ws.Range("B3").Copy` to `ws.Range("B3:F3").Copy`... That should do it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure below will take all of the cells in the current range selection and convert any formulas to values. Quick, easy, and flexible.

```
Sub PasteValues()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In ActiveWindow.RangeSelection
        rngCell.Value = rngCell.Value
    Next rngCell            
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sort of method to adapt to your needs.  Cells(row, col) instead of Range("A1")

```
Private Sub SimpleCopyPaste()
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim rowNum As Long

    LastCol = Sheets("data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    rowNum = 3      
    'You can get to the row number several different ways.  
    'Your original question was for B3,C3,D3, so this example just sets Row3
    For col = 2 to lastCol
        Sheets("data").Cells(rowNum, col).Value = Sheets("data").Range("B3").Value
    next col
End Sub
```